# How can I send an HTTP POST request to url with action=fetch in python?

Tags: python, http, httprequest

I want to send an HTTP POST request to url.
The response would be a valid JSON object.

I made this little python script for that, but unfortunately it's not working correctly.

```
import httplib, urllib

host = 'www.google.com'
url = 'www.google.com'


values = urllib.urlencode(values)

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request("POST", url)
response = conn.getresponse()

data = response.read()

print 'Response: ', response.status, response.reason
print data
print response
```

Comment: `unfortunately it's not working correctly`. You'll need to tell us **how** it is not working. Do you get an exception? Then post the traceback. Do you get a 500 response instead? **Show us** what goes wrong, and what you expected instead.

Comment: I didn't post any example Do you mean vittore's post? You didn't copy the code from that post correctly. `headers` is a keyword argument.

Comment: I see that this is a site that tries to filter out developers that actually know how to create proper web requests. I am not sure helping you here is going to get you hired there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
  import requests, time
  url = 'www.something.com/nextstep'
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  values = {'action' : 'fetch', 'number' : '1'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
  uuid = r.json()['uuid']       

  time.sleep(1)
  values = {'action':'solve', 'number':1, 'uuid':''}
  url = 'www.something.com/anothernextstep'
  r = requests.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
```

Comment: @user3099995 added line how you getting json from response.

Comment: @user3099995 Well it means response is not well formatted json. May be you need to provide some additional parameters in payload.

Comment: @user3099995 obviosly the same way as first time. updated answer anyway

Comment: I just wondering... is there any way to see the response (for feedback)?

Comment: @user3099995 exactly the same way we did it already `r.json()`